# Does Per-Body Damping Compound With Space Damping in Pymunk?

Tags: python, pygame, simulation, pymunk

Making some simulations for a project.

My question is does the damping value of a body compound with the damping value of the pymunk space (if there is any)?

For example, if I have a pymunk space, SPACE, with SPACE.damping = 0.9 and then I have a body, BODY, where I set its BODY.update_velocity() method to take a damping value of 0.5, will BODY's damping be 0.9*0.5 (or some other composition) or will it be 0.5?

Let me know if I can make my question more clear and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damping is used like this:

1. When stepping the space (space.step), the damping that will be used is calculated by `damping = pow(space.damping, dt)`
2. Next it will call the velocity function of each body in the space, passing in the calculated damping from step 1 (just below the damping calculation in step 1)
3. The default velocity function does this calculation to set the velocity: 
   `body.velocity = body.velocity * damping + (gravity + body.force / body.mass) * dt`
4. And this to set the angular velocity:
   `body.angular_velocity = body.angular_velocity*damping + body.torque / body.moment * dt`

You can find the actual code for step 1&2 here: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/chipmunk_src/src/cpSpaceStep.c#L399

The code for step 3 & 4 here: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/chipmunk_src/src/cpBody.c#L494
(I translated the c code in the source to python/pymunk terms in my answer above)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for pointing me to the source code.

So, I'm still unclear: does the damping value of a modified velocity function interact with the space.damping in any way (composed, multiplied, added, etc.)?

Comment: The damping from the space is passed into the body velocity function. If you have a custom velocity function its fully up to you what you want to do with the damping that is passed in.